# How do I get sIBL GUI to work on Mac OS X?

Tags: python, customization

I downloaded the sIBL GUI, and it works as a standalone perfectly. I watched a tutorial on how to use it in Blender at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o198WjOBtIE -- but in User Prefs when I attempt to specify ("accept") the path to the sIBL GUI, the line remains BLANK. Now even though the python script is loaded, I cannot load sIBL GUI, probably because Blender still doesn't know where it is. What's the secret to getting this to work on Mac?

Comment: I think Blender is looking for ".exe" but on Mac, this is ".app" instead, so Blender can't see it (??)

Comment: Even copying the complete path in text and pasting it into this field doesn't work.  :-(

Comment: When you say complete path, have you tried `appname.app/Contents/MacOS/appname`?

Comment: What sambler says, should work. I also have a mac and sIBL GUI works flawlessly with Blender.

Comment: I have the same issue - doesn't matter what I wrote to "sIBL GUI executable" path, enter = empty field, blender 2.76, 2.78 on OS X 10.11.6 Reported as an issue https://bitbucket.org/jedfrechette/sibl_gui_for_blender/issues